# Why am I unable to run"npm run dev" after installing npm to VS code via bash?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio, npm

"npm run dev" not working for VS code...

Manojitanjan Chakma@ManojitPC MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/lsapp
$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\wamp64\www\lsapp
>   npm run development

npm ERR! file C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! spawn C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14 ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manojitanjan Chakma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-26T18_31_13_113Z-debug.log